# Return the value of a variable when one of them is defined in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm just trying to 'merge' two variables, and return the value the variable that is defined in the dataLayer.

`function() {`
`if ({{dlv - klaviyo - email}} !== 'undefined') {`
`return ({{dlv - klaviyo - email}}); }`
`else if ({{dlv - footer - email}} !== 'undefined') {`
`return ({{dlv - footer - email}}); }`
`else {`
`return ('undefined');`
`}}`

The 'else if' part is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a proper undefined check:

```js
function(){
  if ({{dlv - klaviyo - email}} !== 'undefined' && typeof {{dlv - klaviyo - email}} !== 'undefined'){ 
    return ({{dlv - klaviyo - email}}); 
  } else if ({{dlv - footer - email}} !== 'undefined' && typeof {{dlv - footer - email}} !== 'undefined')) { 
    return ({{dlv - footer - email}}); 
  } else { 
    return 'undefined'; 
  }
}
```

Try to keep indentations intact. Makes it easier for humans to read your code.

If this still doesn't catch your case, add console logging or inspect the values of your DLVs and see what you're not catching.